# How to export a map to a 2000 * 2000 page format

Tags: qgis

I have a 3500 scale OpenStreet card that I want to export in PDF. Every time I try, QGIS crashes.
Anyone have an idea to export large plans to one page?

Comment: Export from view or layout, size of the page, DPI resolution output, layers used? Would be better to provide more infos to get a chance for a relevant answer. Do not hesitate to edit your answer with more infos

Comment: Possible workaround: exprt as image file, than create pdf

Comment: thanks for yours reply, but i just tried on the openstreetmap map visualizations. It crashes a few seconds later, I tried on such a tiff, echelle 3500 dpi:300.